# Sentence Wrap inside a HTML table cell

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML code, where i need to wrap the sentence inside the cell, as the sentence is overlapping to the next cells. how to use a wrap function ? I need to keep the below code intact and put the extra function of wrapping.

```html
 <table width="100%">
        <table-body border = "1px solid black">
            <table-row border = "1px solid black" font-size="10px" background-color="#00a7d4" text-align="center" color="white">

<table-cell border = "1px solid black" number-columns-spanned="3"  padding="3px">
                    
                        <block><apex:outputText >{!QL.SBQQ__Product__r.Short_Description_Slides_Appliances__c}
                            </apex:outputText></block></table-cell>

            </table-row>
            
        </table-body>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can try with word-wrap: break-word if you want to wrap the cell to match the content. Otherwise you can try to use overflow:scroll to make it scrollable.

```css
td {
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
  <table border = "1">
         <tr>
            <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
         </tr>
         
         <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2dsadasdasdasdasdasdasda</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
```